# Stripe blocked frame origin

Tags: stripe-payments

I have custom stripe form so I am using standard javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

I try to get the token with:

```
<script>
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('xxx'); 
  Stripe.card.createToken({
      number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
      cvc: '100',
      exp: '10/2018'
    },
    function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  );
</script>
```

Code is pretty straight forward but I receive exception in my browser:

```
(index):3 Uncaught SecurityError: 
Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:3000" 
from accessing a frame with origin "https://js.stripe.com". 
Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the response headers for the request? Sounds like `https://localhost:3000` is not listed as an allowed protocol/domain/port.

Comment: I found that I have not enter valid credit card info (I passed jQuery obj into expiration date parameter and not its value ... ). It took me some time to realise this .. :) Asking question actually helped ...

Answer (score 5):

I found that I was not entering valid credit card info (I passed jQuery object into expiration date parameter and not its value ... ).

Comment: The fact that you posted this answer to your own question probably just saved me hours of debugging as I made the exact same mistake. Thank you for doing this and not just deleting your question!